# Randomized contraction algorithm for the Min Cuts in a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, kargers-algorithm

I have tried to write an implementation of Karger's algorithm for solving the min cut problem. Here's my code

```
def randomVertices(g): 
    v1 = g.keys() [random.randint(0,len(g)-1)]
    v2 = g[v1] [random.randint(0,len(g[v1])-1)]
    return v1, v2


def mergeVertices(g):
    v1,v2 = randomVertices(g)

    g[v1].extend(g[v2])

    for x in g[v2]:
        l = g[x]
        for i in range(0,len(l)):
            if l[i] == v2: 
                l[i] = v1        

    while v1 in g[v1]:
        g[v1].remove(v1)

    del g[v2]

def minCut(g): 
    while len(g) > 2: 
        mergeVertices(g)
    return len(g[g.keys()[0]])
```

It's not commented but it should be pretty self-explanatory. 'g' is a dictionary whose keys are the vertices of the graph, each with values the vertices it is connected to. randomVertices gives me the edge that I want to contract, while mergeVertices updates the dictionary (and hence the graph) by deleting the second vertex, updating the values of the keys which were linked to this vertex, and getting rid of the self-loops. 
It looks okay to me but if I run it on any test graph I get a KeyError at the `l = g[x]` stage, and I can't understand why this is happening. Was hoping that some of you may be able to help me. Thanks.

EDIT: my code is actually fine, the error was in the way I loaded the file with the adjacent list. Cobarzan, thank you for pointing out that I'm not actually picking edges uniformly.

Comment: if x is in `g[v2]` does that automatically mean it is in g at that point?

Comment: Yes, every value in the dictionary is always equal to some key, because when I delete a vertex I update all the values that were equal to it.

Comment: did you print `g` to see what it looked like before you got the keyerror?

Comment: @HariSeldon Though not related to your actual question, but very important for the algorithm, if you are trying to implement the standard Karger's algorithm, you should really pick edges **uniformly at random**. That means that if you have m edges in your graph at some point, each should have equal chances of being picked (1/m). In the current implementation, you do not do that since edges incident to low degree vertices have higher chances to be picked than edges incident to high degree vertices. This note might also dramatically change the implementation.